# How to ask for an answer when no one responded to a question?

Tags: discussion

"'all of which' vs. 'any one of which' vs. 'each of which'" is still unanswered. How could I ask for an answer if I don't have the way to offer a bounty?

Since there are at least 50 unanswered questions, I think this question could be of general interest, even because if the norm is that users don't get answers they could be tempeted to not ask any other question in the future or, which is worst, they could ask on EL&U.

Answer (score 2):

I think you know the system pretty well. In order to offer a bounty, you'll have to earn enough rep first.

The question you allude to was only asked yesterday. Some regulars may not have even seen it yet. I think you are painting this picture to be more dire than it really is.

You might also try editing the question to make it more clear or interesting to the community.

As for that last part: asking on ELU, which is "worse" for some reason. If the question is on a topic that would interest serious linguists and those who study the language at an advanced level, it should go to ELU. If it is more of an elementary question caused primarily by unfamiliarity with English, then it is better here.

50 or so "unanswered" questions out of over 3000 cast is a pretty low rate. Moreover, some of these questions **do** have helpful answers (like [this one](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/13058)), only these answers are in the form of comments to the O.P., as opposed to full-fledged answers. But the users are still being helped.

Comment: I've just answered the question, but I can't help feeling it would have made more sense to ask about usage overlaps and distinctions involving *all, each, **every***, rather than *all, **any one of**, each*. I can't deny I may also have been influenced by the [Username problem](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/865/)